# In-place type conversion of a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a NumPy array of `int32`, how do I convert it to `float32` **in place**?  So basically, I would like to do

```
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
```

without copying the array.  It is big.

The reason for doing this is that I have two algorithms for the computation of `a`.  One of them returns an array of `int32`, the other returns an array of `float32` (and this is inherent to the two different algorithms).  All further computations assume that `a` is an array of `float32`.

Currently I do the conversion in a C function called via `ctypes`.  Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Using `ctypes` is as much "in Python" as using `numpy`. :)

Comment: @Karl: No, because I have to code and compile the C function myself.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you're probably SOL on this one.

Comment: Naive question: How can you tell a=a.astype(numpy.float32) is making a copy? Python slows to a crawl and your disk starts thrashing?

Comment: @Andrew: There are many ways to tell if it returns a copy.  One of them is to read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Comment: What do you think about using a = np.cast['f'](a) with `a` your `int32` array?

Comment: This does not perform an in-place conversion.  It does the same as the code in the original question.  (Don't bother to try to correct it -- it won't get any better than in the accepted answer.)

Comment: It's just the way the functions in this dictionary work.  If I'd ask "why does `print` print its arguments?" or "why does `a + b` denote the sum a `a` and `b`?", how would you answer those questions?

Comment: In-place simply means "using the same memory as the original array".  Have a look at the accepted answer -- the last part shows that the new values indeed have overwritten the same memory.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can make a view with a different dtype, and then copy in-place into the view:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10, dtype='int32')
y = x.view('float32')
y[:] = x

print(y)
```

yields

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)
```

To show the conversion was in-place, note that copying *from* `x` to `y` altered `x`:

```
print(x)
```

prints

```
array([         0, 1065353216, 1073741824, 1077936128, 1082130432,
       1084227584, 1086324736, 1088421888, 1090519040, 1091567616])
```

Comment: Note for those (like me) that want conversion between dtype of different byte-size (e.g. 32 to 16 bits): This method fails because y.size <> x.size. Logical once you think about it :-(

Comment: Was this solution working for some older version of Numpy? When I do `np.arange(10, dtype=np.int32).view(np.float32)` on Numpy 1.8.2, I get `array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.40129846e-45, ... [snip] ... 1.26116862e-44], dtype=float32)`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: That's expected. The conversion occurs when you assign `y[:] = x`.

Comment: to clarify the point made about the itemsize (number of bits) referred to by the original answer and @Juh_  e.g.:
`a = np.arange(10, dtype='float32');
b = a[::-1];
c = np.vstack((a,b));
d = c.view('float64')`
This code takes 10 + 10 float32 and results in 10, rather than 20 float64

Comment: This in-place change may save on memory use, but it is slower than a simple `x.astype(float)` conversion. I wouldn't recommend it unless your script is bordering on MemoryError.

Answer (score 167):

Update: This function only avoids copy if it can, hence this is not the correct answer for this question. [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396247/3798217) is the right one.

---

```
a = a.astype(numpy.float32, copy=False)
```

numpy astype has a copy flag. Why shouldn't we use it ?

Comment: Once this parameter is supported in a NumPy release, we could of course use it, but currently it's only available in the development branch.  And at the time I asked this question, it didn't exist at all.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It is now supported, at least in my version (1.7.1).

Comment: It seems to work perfectly in python3.3 with the latest numpy version.

Comment: I find this to be around 700x slower than a = a.view((float, len(a.dtype.names)))

Comment: The copy flag only says that if the change can be done without a copy, it will be done without a copy. However it the type is different it will still always copy.

Comment: `import numpy as np; x = np.ones(int(1.9e9), dtype=np.int64); x.astype(np.float64, copy=False)` gives out of memory error on a machine with 16 Gb memory. It might still create intermediates.

Answer (score 14):

You can change the array type without converting like this:

```
a.dtype = numpy.float32
```

but first you have to change all the integers to something that will be interpreted as the corresponding float.  A very slow way to do this would be to use python's `struct` module like this:

```
def toi(i):
    return struct.unpack('i',struct.pack('f',float(i)))[0]
```

...applied to each member of your array.

But perhaps a faster way would be to utilize numpy's ctypeslib tools (which I am unfamiliar with)

**- edit -**

Since ctypeslib doesnt seem to work, then I would proceed with the conversion with the typical `numpy.astype` method, but proceed in block sizes that are within your memory limits:

```
a[0:10000] = a[0:10000].astype('float32').view('int32')
```

...then change the dtype when done.

Here is a function that accomplishes the task for any compatible dtypes (only works for dtypes with same-sized items) and handles arbitrarily-shaped arrays with user-control over block size:

```
import numpy

def astype_inplace(a, dtype, blocksize=10000):
    oldtype = a.dtype
    newtype = numpy.dtype(dtype)
    assert oldtype.itemsize is newtype.itemsize
    for idx in xrange(0, a.size, blocksize):
        a.flat[idx:idx + blocksize] = \
            a.flat[idx:idx + blocksize].astype(newtype).view(oldtype)
    a.dtype = newtype

a = numpy.random.randint(100,size=100).reshape((10,10))
print a
astype_inplace(a, 'float32')
print a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Honestly, I don't think this is very useful for **big** arrays -- it is way too slow.  Reinterpreting the data of the array as a different type is easy -- for example by calling `a.view(numpy.float32)`.  The hard part is actually converting the data.  `numpy.ctypeslib` only helps with reinterpreting the data, not with actually converting it.

Comment: ok.  I wasn't sure what your memory/processor limitations were.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Doing it blockwise is a good idea -- probably the best you can get with the current NumPy interface.  But in this case, I will probably stick to my current ctypes solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Time spent reading data**

```
t1=time.time() ; V=np.load ('udata.npy');t2=time.time()-t1 ; print( t2 )
```

95.7923333644867

```
V.dtype
```

dtype('>f8')

```
V.shape
```

(3072, 1024, 4096)

**Creating new array **

```
t1=time.time() ; V64=np.array( V, dtype=np.double); t2=time.time()-t1 ; print( t2 )
```

1291.669689655304

**Simple in-place numpy conversion**

```
t1=time.time() ; V64=np.array( V, dtype=np.double); t2=time.time()-t1 ; print( t2 )
```

205.64322113990784

**Using astype**

```
t1=time.time() ; V = V.astype(np.double) ; t2=time.time()-t1 ; print( t2 )
```

400.6731758117676

**Using view**

```
t1=time.time() ; x=V.view(np.double);V[:,:,:]=x ;t2=time.time()-t1 ; print( t2 )
```

556.5982494354248

*Note that each time I cleared the variables. Thus simply let python handle the conversion is the most efficient.*

Comment: There were several reasons why I wanted to avoid the copy. The main reasons were that it uses twice the amount of memory, which often simply wouldn't fit. Another reason was that I needed the pointer to the array to remain stable, since there was some C code still holding the same pointer. Raw speed was one concern, but not the main concern. I realize that other people visitiing this question have other requirments, so for them having these benchmarks may be useful.

Comment: Mistake: "Creating new array" and "Simple in-place numpy conversion" looks same. Please correct. @Arphy

Answer (score -1):

```py
import numpy as np
arr_float = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float32)
arr_int = arr_float.view(np.float32)
```

use view() and parameter 'dtype' to change the array in place.

Comment: The goal of the question was to actually _convert_ the data in place. After correcting the type in the last line to `int`, this answer would only reinterpret the existing data as a different type, which isn't what I was asking for.

Comment: what do you mean? dtype is just the appearance of data in memory, it really workes.However in np.astype,  parameter 'casting' can control convert method default 'unsafe'.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the first accepted answer. However arr_.astype(new_dtype, copy=False) still returns a newly allocated array. How to satisfied the `dtype`, `order`, and `subok` requirements to return a copy of array? I don't solve it.

Answer (score -5):

Use this:

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[15, 30, 88, 31, 33],
       [53, 38, 54, 47, 56],
       [67,  2, 74, 10, 16],
       [86, 33, 15, 51, 32],
       [32, 47, 76, 15, 81]], dtype=int32)

In [106]: float32(a)
Out[106]: 
array([[ 15.,  30.,  88.,  31.,  33.],
       [ 53.,  38.,  54.,  47.,  56.],
       [ 67.,   2.,  74.,  10.,  16.],
       [ 86.,  33.,  15.,  51.,  32.],
       [ 32.,  47.,  76.,  15.,  81.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is not a copy? Can you check it and explain a little bit more?

Answer (score -5):

`a = np.subtract(a, 0., dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Why should this be an **in place** conversion? `numpy.subtract` is returning a copy, isn't it? Only the name `a` reused for another chunk of data... Please explain, if I am wrong about this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, it seems you are correct - a copy is produced.