# Convert ndarray from float64 to integer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've got an `ndarray` in python with a `dtype` of `float64`. I'd like to convert the array to be an array of integers. How should I do this?

`int()` won't work, as it says it can't convert it to a scalar. Changing the `dtype` field itself obviously doesn't work, as the actual bytes haven't changed. I can't seem to find anything on Google or in the documentation - what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `.astype`.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.float64)
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> a.astype(numpy.int64)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy.ndarray.astype) for more options.

Comment: small point to note. It does not do rounding but truncates

Answer (score 13):

While `astype` is probably the "best" option there are several other ways to convert it to an integer array. I'm using this `arr` in the following examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=float)
>>> arr
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

### The `int*` functions from NumPy

```
>>> np.int64(arr)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.int_(arr)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

### The NumPy `*array` functions themselves:

```
>>> np.array(arr, dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.asarray(arr, dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.asanyarray(arr, dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

### The `astype` method (that was already mentioned but for completeness sake):

```
>>> arr.astype(int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Note that passing `int` as dtype to `astype` or `array` will default to a default integer type that depends on your platform. For example on Windows it will be `int32`, on 64bit Linux with 64bit Python it's `int64`. If you need a specific integer type and want to avoid the platform "ambiguity" you should use the corresponding NumPy types like `np.int32` or `np.int64`.

Answer (score 6):

There's also a really useful discussion about converting the array in place, [In-place type conversion of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array).  If you're concerned about copying your array (which is what`astype()` does) definitely check out the link.

Answer (score 2):

All I used is

```
numpyfloat = (1.0, 2.0, 4.0)
a = numpy.array(numpyfloat, dtype=numpy.int)
```

That's just it