# Create a random noise image with the same mean and (skewed) distribution as another image

Tags: python

I have an image represented as a uint16 numpy array (`orig_arr`) with a skewed distribution. I would like to create a new array (`noise_arr`) of random values, but that matches the mean and standard deviation of `orig_img`.

I believe this will require two main steps:

1. Measure the mean and distribution of `orig_arr`
2. Create a new array of random values using the mean and distribution measured in step 1

I'm pretty much lost on how to do this, but here's a sample image and a bit of code to get you started:

Sample image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bevwW-NHshIVRqni5O62QB7bxcxnUier (looks blank but it's not)

```
orig_arr = cv2.imread('sample_img.tif', -1)
orig_mean = np.mean(orig_arr)
orig_sd = np.std(orig_arr)

print(orig_mean)
18.676384933578962

print(orig_sd)    
41.67964688299941
```

Comment: Probably need to see the distribution of your original image as the second step to decide which family to sample from in step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `scipy.stats.skewnorm` might do the trick.  It lets you characterize skewed normal distributions, and also sample data from skewed normal distributions.

Now...  maybe that's a bad assumption for your data...  maybe it's not skew-normal, but this is the first thing I'd try.

```
# import skewnorm
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

# find params
a, loc, scale = skewnorm.fit(orig_arr)

# mimick orig distribution with skewnorm
# keep size and shape the same as orig_arr
noise_arr = skewnorm(a, loc, scale).rvs(orig_arr.size).astype('uint16').reshape(orig_array.shape)
```

There's more detail about exploring this kind of data...  plotting it...  comparing it...  over here:  [How to create uint16 gaussian noise image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599018/how-to-create-uint16-gaussian-noise-image/54600502)

Also...  I think using `imshow` and setting `vmin` and `vmax` will let you look at an image or heatmap of your data that is sensitive to the range.  That is demonstrated in the link above as well.

Hope that helps!