# In-place type conversion of a Numpy array again?

Tags: python, numpy

I have got an array of `floats`and I would like to cast it into `int`.

```
a1 = np.ones(10)
a2 = a1.astype(int, copy=False)
a2.dtype # int
a1.dtype # float
```

What's going on here? I thought `astype(int, copy=False)` would cast types in-places. But it doesn't appear to do so?

related question: [In-place type conversion of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array?rq=1)

Comment: I thought it might be due to size differences between pure python `int` and `np.float64`, but I tried with `np.int64` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Start reading here:  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`copy` argument documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

> If this is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements
>   are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy.

It can't actually convert the type in place. It only works if the input array is already of the dtype you want; otherwise, it has to make a copy anyway.

Comment: I think this seems correct, but what can `astype` change, if not the `dtype`?

Comment: @wim: It can only avoid making a new array if the original already looks exactly the way you want it. When making a new array, it can change the dtype, memory order, and particular array subclass.

Comment: This is simply a way of avoiding an unnecessary copy if you have an array object of unknown type and you have to cast it to a specific one. This is probably not that often needed using numpy from Python, where you can get the same operation to work regardless of type, but in the C internals of numpy you see that done all the time.