# Python numpy subtraction no negative numbers (4-6 gives 254)

Tags: python, numpy, grayscale, subtraction, array-difference

I wish to subtract 2 **gray** human faces from each other to see the difference, but I encounter a problem that subtracting e.g. [4] - [6] gives [254] instead of [-2] (or difference: [2]).

```
print(type(face)) #<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(face.shape) #(270, 270)
print(type(nface)) #<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(nface.shape) #(270, 270)

#This is what I want to do:
sface = face - self.nface #or
sface = np.subtract(face, self.nface)
```

Both don't give negative numbers but instead subtract the rest after 0 from 255.

Output example of sface:

```
[[  8 255   8 ...,   0 252   3]
 [ 24  18  14 ..., 255 254 254]
 [ 12  12  12 ...,   0   2 254]
 ..., 
 [245 245 251 ..., 160 163 176]
 [249 249 252 ..., 157 163 172]
 [253 251 247 ..., 155 159 173]]
```

**My question:**
How do I get sface to be an numpy.ndarray (270,270) with either negative values after subtracting **or** the difference between each point in face and nface? (So not numpy.setdiff1d, because this returns only 1 dimension instead of 270x270)

## Working

From the answer of @ajcr I did the following (abs() for showing subtracted face):

```
face_16 = face.astype(np.int16)
nface_16 = nface.astype(np.int16)
sface_16 = np.subtract(face_16, nface_16)
sface_16 = abs(sface_16)
sface = sface_16.astype(np.int8)
```

Comment: Can't replicate, if I create two numpy arrays full of values in the range 0-255 I can simply do `a - b` and it'll give me negative numbers.

Comment: Your array must be an unsigned integer type - try e.g. `dtype=np.int16`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like the `dtype` of the array is `uint8`. All the numbers will be interpreted as integers in the range 0-255. Here, -2 is equal to 256 - 2, hence the subtraction results in 254.

You need to recast the arrays to a `dtype` which supports negative integers, e.g. `int16` like this ...

```
face = face.astype(np.int16)
```

...and then subtract.

Comment: I now used the following code ( abs() for showing face):

Ok nvm, code doesn't work here, see my post

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with your datatype in the numpy array. You have a uint8 inside it, which seems to wrap around

Have a look at nfac.dtype whichwill show it to you. You have to convert it prior to your calculation operation. Use numpy.ndarray.astype to convert it or have a look at [In-place type conversion of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array)