# Why does numpy array's astype method not modify the input when casting type?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using the astype method of numpy's array object to convert an array from character to integer. For the sake of efficiency I am using copy=False, but I noticed that the original array is actually not modified. How is that possible without declaring b as a new array ?

```
import numpy

a=numpy.array(['0','1']) 
b=a.astype(numpy.int32,copy=False)
print a[0], b[0]
```

Comment: Compare `a.nbytes` and `b.nbytes`.  One is 2, the other 8.  You, and numpy, can't squeeze 2 4byte integers into 2 1byte character slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious problems here. First, the

```
numpy.array(a)
```

in

```
b=numpy.array(a).astype(numpy.int32,copy=False)
```

already makes a copy. Second, from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

> If [the copy parameter] is set to false, **and the dtype, *order*, and *subok* requirements are satisfied**, the input array is returned instead of a copy.

NumPy is simply ignoring `copy=False`, since the dtype mismatch means it needs to copy.

Comment: right, consider the numpy.array(a) as a huge typo :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), a copy is only avoided if,

> copy : bool, optional
>
> By default, astype always returns a newly allocated array. If this is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy.

Because you have a character array and it needs to convert to an int32, I assume this violates the dtype requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I found a convoluted way to do an in-place type conversion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396247/901925

In that example the conversion was from 'int32' to 'float32'.  Adapted to our case:

Initial `x` with a large enough string size:

```
In [128]: x=np.array(['0','1'],dtype='S4')
In [129]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[129]: (173756800, False)    # data buffer location
```

now make a view, and copy values from `x` to the view:

```
In [130]: y=x.view(int)
In [131]: y[:]=x
```

Same data buffer location  (same for `y`)

```
In [132]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[132]: (173756800, False)
```

Now `y` is two ints:

```
In [133]: y
Out[133]: array([0, 1])
```

`x`, which is still `S4`, looks at these bytes in a different way:

```
In [134]: x
Out[134]: 
array([b'', b'\x01'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

So it is possible to perform data type conversions in-place, if byte sizes match, but it is an advanced operation. Both the person asking that question and the one answering it are `numpy` experts.

And `astype,copy=False` is mentioned in another answer, but fails for the same reason as here - it can't perform the conversion without changing the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the docs:

> If copy is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements
>   are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy.

So your dtype requirements are not satisified. The array must be copied