# Numpy inplace dtype conversion

Tags: numpy, memory, type-conversion

16Gb machine gives out of memory error. I doubt if the conversion is really in place.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ones(int(1.5e9), dtype=np.int64)  # 12 Gb
x.astype(np.float64, copy=False)  # gives out of memory error.
```

How to do in-place memory conversion? I want to convert data type and preserve the value. For example 1.0f becomes integer 1.

[In-place type conversion of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Probably can do it by parts. `y = x.view(dtype=np.float64); y[:10000] = x[:10000].astype(np.float64)`

Comment: How is the question you link to not enough to solve your problem? Looks like an exact duplicate to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the `copy` parameter:

> By default, astype always returns a newly allocated array. If this
>       is set to false, and the `dtype`, `order`, and `subok`
>       requirements are satisfied, the input array is returned instead
>       of a copy.

So it's conditional.

```
In [540]: x=np.arange(10)
In [542]: x.dtype
Out[542]: dtype('int32')
In [543]: z=x.astype('float32',copy=False)
In [544]: z
Out[544]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)
In [545]: x.__array_interface__
Out[545]: 
{'data': (188221848, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (10,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [546]: z.__array_interface__
Out[546]: 
{'data': (191273640, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f4')],
 'shape': (10,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f4',
 'version': 3}
```

`z` has different memory location.

---

The accepted answer in your link appears to work

```
In [549]: z=x.view('float32')
In [550]: z[:]=x
In [551]: z
Out[551]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)
In [552]: x
Out[552]: 
array([         0, 1065353216, 1073741824, 1077936128, 1082130432,
       1084227584, 1086324736, 1088421888, 1090519040, 1091567616])
In [553]: z
Out[553]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)
In [555]: x.__array_interface__
Out[555]: 
{'data': (188221848, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (10,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [556]: z.__array_interface__
Out[556]: 
{'data': (188221848, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f4')],
 'shape': (10,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f4',
 'version': 3}
```

This works because `z` shares memory with `x`, but with a different `dtype`.  When copied from `x` to `z`, they are converted to match the new dtype.  Memory locations is preserved. However I can't guarantee that there wasn't a temporary buffer.

---

In case it isn't clear, conversion form `int32` to `float32` requires a change in the underlying bytes.  The bit representation of integers is different from that of floats.

```
In [594]: np.array(1, 'int32').tobytes()
Out[594]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
In [595]: np.array(1, 'float32').tobytes()
Out[595]: b'\x00\x00\x80?'
```

Comment: float32 and int32 both uses same amount of memory. but astype still makes new copy, which is not necessary and inefficient ...

Comment: What does efficiency have to do with it.  Each 4byte block has to go through the same conversion process.  Whether it gets written back to the same or different memory location shouldn't make much difference in 'speed'.

Comment: I guess making copy is slower than doing the operation in place because cpu don't have to read/write an extra cache line of memory. prefetch should mask memory latency. don't know if prefetch work better without that copying. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928995/how-do-cache-lines-work Making copy is less memory efficient for sure.

Comment: That memory cache might matter with very large arrays.  I just did some timings.  for `arange(10000)` the 2nd method is modestly faster; for `arange(1000000)` 15x.  Times are still in the ns/µs range.

Comment: The `z[:]=x` rewrites all the data byes (inplace).  `z`  float is then the correct way to view them.  `x.view('float32')` shows the proper `1.0`.

Comment: You are right. I missed that. At least numpy can work here.