# Why can't I convert floats in an array into integers?

Tags: python, numpy, integer

I want to convert the elements(float) into integer, but it seems not working.

```
#get an array from a matrix
pre_dataY = data[:, -1]
print(pre_dataY)
# float to integer
for i in range(len(pre_dataY):
    pre_dataY[i]=int(pre_dataY[i]) 
print(pre_dataY)
```

however, the output is :

```
[ 3.  2.  9. ...,  7.  5.  5.]

[ 3.  2.  9. ...,  7.  5.  5.]
```

I don't see why that is?

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?

Comment: yes, i import numpy

Comment: `numpy` arrays preserve the type. Do `new_array=pre_dataY.astype(np.int)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-place type conversion of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Thx :) dealt with that ~

Answer (score 0):

use mapping:

```
print map(int, pre_dataY)
```

Mapping create a new list with your values

Comment: But `pre_dataY` is an array, and presumably the OP wants it to remain so.  If it started as a list, the inplace change would have worked.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a closing parens in the loop:

You have:

```
for i in range(len(pre_dataY):
```

It should be:

```
for i in range(len(pre_dataY)):
```

Comment: This answer looks OK but could use some more details and an explanation.