# Problem assigning element to Python numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 3D array defined and initialized as follows. May I know why the following assignment does not work? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
xy = np.array([[(0,0) for _ in np.arange(0,2,0.5)] for _ in np.arange(0,2,0.5)])
xy[(0,0)] = (0,0.5)
print(xy[(0,0)])
```

Output:

```
[0 0]
```

Desired output:

```
[0 0.5]
```

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the array?

Comment: int32, may I know how to convert that to float?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array

Comment: That code looks bizarre, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this just some example code? That array creation is _painful_. Take a look at my answer for a far simpler way of doing things.

Comment: Try `xy=np.zeros((4,4,2)]`.  This makes a float dtype array of the right size, and much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to below code:

```
import numpy as np
xy = np.array([[(0,0) for _ in np.arange(0,2,0.5)] for _ in np.arange(0,2,0.5)]).astype('float')
xy[(0,0)] = (0,0.5)
print(xy[(0,0)])
```

Output

```
[0.  0.5]
```

Comment: I get an error when running this: _ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 4_

Comment: @AlexanderCécile check your version may be as I didnt get any error.

Comment: What version of Python and NumPy are you using?

Comment: Instead of using `view`, use `dtype=float` in the array creation directly, or just use `xy = 1. * xy`. You are assigning the view to `xy`, so the original array cannot be accessed by name anymore. Why use `view`in the first place, then? You *can* of course use `xy.view(int)` to get the the original array, if that is what you want. Using `view` here at all is a strange choice, and very confusing.

Comment: To add onto what @JanChristophTerasa said, you could also use the aptly-named [`.astype()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a version with proper array creation, assignment, and variable names:

```py
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.zeros(shape=(4, 4, 2))

arr_1[0, 0] = [0, 0.5]
```

Output of `print(arr_1[0, 0])`: `[0.  0.5]`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This answers the question, and fixes the issues of the original code: 1. The array should be created with a float type in the first place, making the `view` unnecessary. 2. The creation of an n-d array of zeros using python list comprehensions instead of `np.zeros` is unreadable. 3. Using tuples for indexing is error prone, and syntactically unnecessary.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thank you... Not only is the list comprehension an unidiomatic mess, I imagine that it is really inefficient.

Comment: For a (4, 4, 2) array the absolute performance hit should be negligible, unless this is done a million times.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa It won’t make a difference here, you’re right, as you can imagine it’s really a matter of learning good habits and principles.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, that's why I upvoted your answer.