# How do I interpret a uint32 as a float32 using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Using Numpy, how do I take a uint32 and interpret the bits as a float32?

For example, given

```
x = numpy.uint32(1234)
```

I would like to take the raw bit representation of `x` (0x000004D2) and interpret it as a float32 (1.729E-42).

Thanks.

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float)

Comment: `x.view(np.float32)` should do it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Perfect, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array