# Numpy overflow with np.divide(). RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars

Tags: python, image, numpy, integer-overflow, uint

I am running the following code on 2 images:

```
ndvi = np.divide(img8 - img4, img8+img4)

invalid = (ndvi > 1).any()
if invalid:
    print("Stopping Execution")
    print(ndvi)
```

`img8` and `img4` are 2 images and have all positive values.
`ndvi` is (img8-img4)/(img8+img4)

Hence, by definition, all elements of ndvi should be between -1 and 1.
But I am getting some values>1

The dtypes of all the variables in this context are 'uint16'

When I check the index of the invalid values, and ran the individual code:

```
temp = (img8[88][118]-img4[88][118])/(img8[88][118]+img4[88][118])
```

I got the following warning:

```
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars
```

The values are:
img8[88][118] = 1462
img4[88][118] = 1652

The values themself are not large to result in an overflow, but when array sizes become large overflow happens.

Comment: Perhaps the values in `img8` and/or `img4` are not what you think they are. Print them

Comment: Also, just so you are aware, if a value in `img4` is greater than the corresponding value in `img8` then you *will* get negative values

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, I understand. I meant it will be between -1 and 1.

Comment: So, 1 particular invalid value was occuring at index (88,118).
I printed the corresponding img values:
 img4[88][118]=1652
img8[88][118]=1462

So, ndvi[88][118] should be -0.06101

But it's reporting it to be 20.9845

Comment: Please print dtypes of everything (img8, img4, img4+img8, img8-img4)

Comment: It **might** be due to the way `np.divide` works with nested/multi-dimensional arrays. Post a [mcve]

Comment: I think I found the error, when I do: `(img8[88][118]-img4[88][118])/(img8[88][118]+img4[88][118])`
I get a warning: "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars"

But I fail to understand why this is an overflow

Comment: @Gulzar All the dtypes are 'uint16'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subtracting a large number from a small one and both are `unitXX`, you get an overflow (really, an [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow#:%7E:text=The%20term%20arithmetic%20underflow%20(also,central%20processing%20unit%20(CPU)))), and the result is the modulo-XX of the negative number, which is a large number.
This is because `uint` can't represent a negative number, and instead holds a large positive.

This modulo is actually adding maxint ([==65535](https://www.google.com/search?q=max%20int%20for%20uint16&rlz=1C1GCEU_enDE962DE962&oq=max%20int%20for%20uint16&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.4028j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) to the negative

In this case, for the index you specified,

```
img8[88][118]-img4[88][118] == 1462 - 1652 == -190 == 65535 - 190 = 65345
```

Divide that by `1462 + 1652 == 3114` and get `20.984264611432241490044958253051`

---

Solution:

[Convert the dtypes to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array) before dividing, and usually work with floats for images, rather than uint.

Floats don't (normally) have the underflow issue for simple subtraction, as they are built to also represent negatives.

Also would work is using `int` rather than `uint` but stick to floats for your own sake.